# React - Can't use hooks in custom hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have weird issue. I'm trying to create new hooks in reactjs. But i cannot use useEffect, useState and other React Hooks in my custom hook. I'm researching it but i couldn't find any solution. Here is my custom hook:

```js
export function useStore(initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);  
  const store = state;

  return store;
}
```

When im trying to use: useStore('foo'); i get this error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See error link to react (I can't share link...) for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

I also tried to delete useState hook in my code. And it worked that's why in my point of view that problem is hooks. Can someone help me?

Thank you :)

Comment: The hook looks fine. Could you give us an example of component with this hook that leads to the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this about where you call `useStore` from - which you don't show. That call should be in React Function or another custom hook, but probably isn't.

Hooks can be called from within custom hooks as stated here:

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>   ... Call Hooks from custom Hooks

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions.

It works when removing `useState` as it is this builtin hook that actually issues the error (see https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3278d242184a13add3f25f683b77ef9a6a2305f3/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js).

Comment: Sorry about that. I use it in the real react component.

Comment: I'm trying to create custom hook... So it should work but it doesn't. I'm not trying to handle it in regular JavaScript function.

Comment: @EmirhanEngin oh ok. Could you show the calling component?

Comment: Thank you so much... I was trying to use it in class component.

Answer (score 1):

**useCounter, useSlider, usePicker**

You can write hooks using other hooks. Consider these examples -

[image: app preview]

A custom `useCounter` hook shows us how we can write small child components which [send their state upwards](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent component -

```js
const useCounter = (init = 0) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(init)
  return [
    value, 
    <div>
      <button onClick={_ => setValue(value - 1)}>-</button>
      {value}
      <button onClick={_ => setValue(value + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  ]
}
```

In `MyApp`, when `useCounter` is called, we get the stateful value *and* the stateful counter component -

```js
const initialOrder =
  { muffin: 0, cakes: 0, pies: 0, ... }

const MyApp = ({ order = initialOrder }) => {
  const [muffins, muffinCounter] = useCounter(order.muffins)
  const [cakes, cakeCounter] = useCounter(order.cakes)
  const [pies, piesCounter] = useCounter(order.pies)

  // ...

  return <ul>
    <li>muffins: {muffinCounter}</li>
    <li>cakes: {cakeCounter}</li>
    <li>pies: {piesCounter}</li>
    // ...
  </ul>
}
```

We can make similar components like this `useSlider` custom hook -

```js
const useSlider = ({ min = 0, max = 0, init = 0 }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(init)
  return [
    value, 
    <input
      type="range"
      min={min}
      max={max}
      value={value}
      onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  ]
}
```

And custom hooks made out of custom hooks, `usePicker` -

```js
const usePicker = ({ values = [], init = 0 }) =>
  useSlider({ min: 0, max: values.length - 1, init })
```

```js
const MyApp = ({ order = initialOrder }) => {
  const [muffins, muffinCounter] = useCounter(order.muffins)
  const [cakes, cakeCounter] = useCounter(order.cakes)
  const [pies, piesCounter] = useCounter(order.pies)
  const speeds = ["slow", "medium", "fast", "same-day"]
  const [deliverySpeed, speedPicker] = usePicker({ values: speeds, init: order.deliverySpeed })
  
  // ...
  
  return <ul>
    <li>muffins: {muffinCounter}</li>
    <li>cakes: {cakeCounter}</li>
    <li>pies: {piesCounter}</li>
    <li>speed: {speedPicker} {speeds[deliverySpeed]}</li>
    // ...
  </ul>
}
```

Run the code below to see `useCounter`, `useSlider`, and `usePicker` in action -

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

const useCounter = (init = 0) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(init)
  return [
    value, 
    <div>
      <button onClick={_ => setValue(value - 1)}>-</button>
      {value}
      <button onClick={_ => setValue(value + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  ]
}

const useSlider = ({ min = 0, max = 0, init = 0 }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(init)
  return [
    value, 
    <input type="range" min={min} max={max} value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
  ]
}

const usePicker = ({ values = [], init = 0 }) =>
  useSlider({ min: 0, max: values.length - 1, init })

const initialOrder =
  { muffin: 0, cakes: 0, pies: 0, deliverySpeed: 3 }

const MyApp = ({ order = initialOrder }) => {
  const [muffins, muffinCounter] = useCounter(order.muffins)
  const [cakes, cakeCounter] = useCounter(order.cakes)
  const [pies, piesCounter] = useCounter(order.pies)
  const speeds = ["slow", "medium", "fast", "same-day"]
  const [deliverySpeed, speedPicker] = usePicker({ values: speeds, init: order.deliverySpeed })
  const onSubmit = e =>
    alert("submitted: " + JSON.stringify({ muffins, cakes, pies, deliverySpeed }))
  return <ul>
    <li>muffins: {muffinCounter}</li>
    <li>cakes: {cakeCounter}</li>
    <li>pies: {piesCounter}</li>
    <li>speed: {speedPicker} {speeds[deliverySpeed]} </li>
    <li>{JSON.stringify({ muffins, cakes, pies, deliverySpeed })}</li>
    <li><button onClick={onSubmit}>submit</button></li>
  </ul>
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
body { margin: 0 auto; font-family: monospace; }
ul { padding: 0; }
li { list-style-type: none; background-color: ghostwhite; padding: 0.25rem; margin-bottom: 0.25rem; }
li div { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

**example: useAsync, useJson**

A custom `useAsync` hook allows us to declaratively interact with an asynchronous resources -

```js
function useAsync(func, [_0, _1, _2, _3, _4]) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  useEffect(_ => {
    setLoading(true)
    Promise.resolve(func(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, [func, _0, _1, _2, _3, _4])
  return {loading, error, result}
}
```

In a typical example we just want to do a `fetch` request and parse some JSON. Another custom hook `useJson` built using our first custom hook, `useAsync` -

```js
const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

const useJson = (url = "") =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url])
```

Using `useJson` in `MyComponent` looks like this -

```js
const MyComponent = ({ url = "" }) => {
  const { loading, error, result } = useJson(url) // ✨

  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>

  if (error)
    return <pre style={{color: "tomato"}}>error: {error.message}</pre>

  return <pre>result: {result}</pre>
}
```

Run the code demo below to see `useJson` in action -

[image: useJson]

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React

// fake fetch slows response down so we can see loading
const _fetch = (url = "") =>
  fetch(url).then(x => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000, x)))

function useAsync(func, [_0, _1, _2, _3, _4]) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)
  useEffect(_ => {
    setLoading(true)
    Promise.resolve(func(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, [func, _0, _1, _2, _3, _4])
  return {loading, error, result}
}

const fetchJson = (url = "") =>
  _fetch(url).then(r => r.json())

const useJson = (url = "") =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url])

const MyComponent = ({ url = "" }) => {
  const { loading, error, result } = useJson(url)
  if (loading)
    return <pre>loading...</pre>
  if (error)
    return <pre style={{color: "tomato"}}>error: {error.message}</pre>
  return <pre>result: {JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</pre>
}

const MyApp = () =>
  <main>
    ex 1 (success):
    <MyComponent url="https://httpbin.org/get?foo=bar" />
    ex 2 (error):
    <MyComponent url="https://httpbin.org/status/500" />
  </main>

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.body)
```

```css
pre { background: ghostwhite; padding: 1rem; white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Enjoy your cupcakes!

Answer (score -3):

This is by design. You can only call/use a hook from within a React Function. See more here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions.

You will want to re-think your approach.  Use the different hooks within a component and not within a hook.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {useCustomHookOne} from '../hooks/custom-hook';
import {useCustomHookTwo} from '../hooks/custom-hook';
export default function MyComponent(props) {
    const [state, actions] = useCustomHookOne(initialState, {useState});
    const [state, actions] = useCustomHookTwo(initialState, {useState});
}
```

Comment: But at the documentation, it says we can use hooks in custom hooks. Just needs "use" prefix to our custom hook function name. And i have that... https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook on this example, he uses useState in custom hook.